# Use capistrano to only update with git instead of deploying whole new release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I have a very small app that even uses sqlite3 in production because there are never going to be any issues with multiple writes, etc. I want to use capistrano to quickly and painlessly deploy updates to this app. But when I run `cap production deploy` it dumps the entire app into a release folder and symlinks it to `current`. I know I can include the `production.sqlite3` file in the `deploy.rb` to keep the data but it still seems overkill to clone the entire repo every time I want to push an update.

I couldn't find anything in the capistrano documentation for updates.

Essentially all I need cap to do is

1. make sure my local git HEAD is the same as master
2. SSH into the prod server and do a `git pull`
3. Run `rake db:migrate` if necessary
4. Run `rake assets:clean assets:precompile`
5. Restart `Phusion Passenger`

How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your own bash or ruby script that does this. I think you are missing the point of Capistrano. Cloning the whole repo allows you to do deploy rollbacks, leaving the previous version as is. It takes into account deploys that fail, and will not mess with your production site during the deploy process.

Comment: fair enough. Just wanted to know if I was missing a feature. Thanks